# cmake: oglplus can't find context initialization library (glfw)

Tags: cmake, glfw

I try to build [oglplus](http://oglplus.org/) (C++ wrapper for OpenGL) with cmake (on OS X 10.9 with Xcode 5 / Clang 5.0.0).

But to do so, there is a context initialization library neccesary (i.e. GLUT, GLFW, GLFW3, GL3W, QT4, SDL, wxWidgets). However I tried to compile and install GLFW and GLFW3 multiple times already: But the cmake file from oglplus still won't use them.

The cmake output says:

```
cmake -G Xcode
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing:  PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found GLEW: /usr/local/include /Library/Frameworks/GLEW.framework
-- Could NOT find GL3W
-- Could NOT compile or link with GLFW
-- Could NOT compile or link with GLFW3
-- Could NOT find GLUT (missing:  GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- GLUT header file not found
-- Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing:  wxWidgets_FOUND) 
-- Could NOT find Qt4 (missing:  QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE QT_INCLUDE_DIR QT_LIBRARY_DIR QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Could NOT find SDL
-- GLM header files not found
-- Found PNG: /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib/libpng.dylib
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'SCOPED_ENUMS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'VARIADIC_MACROS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'VARIADIC_TEMPLATES': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'UNIFIED_INITIALIZATION_SYNTAX': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'INITIALIZER_LISTS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'DEFAULTED_FUNCTIONS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'DELETED_FUNCTIONS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'EXPLICIT_CONVERSION_OPERATORS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'FUNCTION_TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_ARGS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'UNICODE_LITERALS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'USER_DEFINED_LITERALS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'CONSTEXPR': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'NOEXCEPT': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'LAMBDAS': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'NULLPTR': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'CHRONO': TRUE
-- Detecting support for c++11 feature 'THREADS': TRUE
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:122 (message):
  No OpenGL context initialization library found!
```

So it seems it can find GLFW/GLFW3, because for some reason it says `Could NOT compile or link with *` instead of `Could NOT find *`. I'm not really familiar with cmake scripts, so I don't know how to examine the reason here.

Any ideas what the problem could be here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the documentation on GitHub? Direct extract:

> ### CMake-based build configuration
>
> The CMake script defines and uses several variables to modify the
>   build configuration, which can be specified on the command-line when
>   invoking cmake (with the `-D` option. see cmake manual for details):
>
> - `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS`: (semicolon-separated) list of paths to additional directories to search when looking for 3rd-party headers like `GL/glew.h`, `GL3/gl3.h`, `GL/glcorearb.h`, etc.
> - `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`: (semicolon-separated) list of paths to additional directories to search when looking for 3rd-party binary libraries like GL, GLEW, GL3W, GLFW, SDL, GLUT, png, etc.

Furthermore, OGLplus is, in fact, a header-only library, so you could simply skip building examples/demos and tests so that no linkage with 3rd party libraries is required at all. You could even copy the headers to the location you want and just use it without running CMake (last time I used it, this approach worked fine, it might have changed, so check it at your own risk).

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem, it seems that GLFW is found and a test program is compiled to check that it works. Simply put, with the MSVC toolchain the test fails.

The simplest fix is to remove/rename the test program (oglplus/config/ext_lib/test_glfw.cpp and/or test_glfw3.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I also had problems with it.

Just make sure that you specify the include- and lib-folders for glfw, glfw3 or whatever you want to use in cmake.

[image: It should look similar to this.]